# Can I use '<' instead of '!=' when iterating over a container?

Tags: c++, stl

Can I use `<` instead of `!=` when iterating over a container?

```
vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = vec.begin(); iter < vec.end; ++iter)
      do_something
```

Comment: The short answer is: no. Your question is about a "container", and not a specific type of a container, so for a generic container, the answer is definitely "no".

Comment: Why would you do this? Use iter != vec.end()

Comment: Sure you can! It just won't work, most of the time.   Seriously, it will work (on some implementations) for `vector` and `string`, and none of the other standard containers - and it only works for them because they are required to store their elements contagiously.   Use `iter != vet.end()` instead.

Answer (score 6):

This works, but only for random access iterators (or any other iterator which defines an `operator<()` ).

In general it's better to use `!=` since this is guaranteed to work (if you use the standard iterator approach)

Answer (score -1):

No you can't use that, just use iter!=vec.end()